# Displaying a default date in a EditText widget

Tags: android

How would I display the current date in the text of a EditText widget dynamically at runtime?

Thanks
patrick

Comment: With updating? Then you'll need a service or something updating the text continuesly!

Comment: I mean an initial value. Let say I have an EditText widget and I want the current date to display in the control when initially displayed. Is there a way to accomplish this in the xml, or programmatically, and what an example might look like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your EditText is declared in the xml file, you have to retrieve it in the code like this

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.your_edittext_id );
```

Then you can easily update it with the current date

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy/MM/dd" ); 
editText.setText( sdf.format( new Date() ));
```

Answer (score 2):

... even better is using the users locale and formatting options:

```
editText.setText( DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date()) );
```