# How input Date from EditText (not automatic, but manual)

Tags: android, date, input, android-edittext

This my code

```
EditText txtdate;
```

This my XML

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtdate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date" />
```

This my class

```
txtdate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtdate);

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

How can I do this?

Comment: used `DatePickerDailog`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying a default date in a EditText widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008558/displaying-a-default-date-in-a-edittext-widget)

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193349/launching-a-datepicker-from-edit-text

Comment: M D : it doesnt work
Mohit : its default not input manual, i need manual input
Haresh Chhelana : it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

txtdate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtdate);

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

You can try then receive the String from EditText and convert it to date. But I wouldn't recommend that: user can enter anything, what you won't be able to parse into valid date. But anyway, here's the code.

```
String string = txtdate.getText().toString();
Date date = Date.parse(string);
String prettyDate = df.format(date);
```

Note, that Date.parse() is deprecated. I use JodaTime library instead. It is pretty simple. Now to the serious staff. 
If you want to get correct date from user, use DatePicker. It is standart thing in Android and it will return you valid date.

Comment: hmmm how can i get that, if not use JodaTime ?

Comment: problem solved, my fault is easy of parameters parsing data